# match a variable to an element inside an array of objects?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, loops

i have a varable:

```
var name = "name";
```

this will be inside an array of objects i have:

```
    var all = [];
    $.each(results, function(i, item){
        all.push({
            rank: i + 1,
            username: item.TopicName,
            mentions: item.LastHourCount,
            totalcount: item.TotalCount,
            urlLg: item.LargeImageUrl,
            urlSm: item.SmallImageUrl,
            shortname: item.ShortName
        });

    });
```

I need to look through the array of objects and find the 'shortname' that matches the variable 'name'.  the objects look like this:

```
Object[
  mentions: 21737
  rank: 2
  shortname: "name"
  totalcount: 59330
  urlLg: null
  urlSm: "http://i.cdn.turner.com/nba/nba/pulse/allstar/2012/img/images-small/howard.png"
  username: "lebron james"
],
```

once i find it set that to a variable:
var showThis = all.[];

Inside the each function as it loops through the json file, is probably where to look for the name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I may be misunderstanding. If you just want to find the entry in `all` with a `shortName` matching `name`, then:

```
var match;
$.each(all, function() {
    if (this.shortName === name) {
        match = this;
        return false;
    }
});
```

That uses [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to loop through the array. In the iterator callback, `this` will refer to the array element, so we just check `this.shortName === name`. The `return false` stops the `each` loop. If there's no match, `match` will keep its default value (`undefined`).

Or as a traditional `for` loop:

```
var match, index, entry;
for (index = 0; index < all.length; ++index) {
    entry = all[index];
    if (entry.shortName === name) {
        match = entry;
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Quick question, is there an easy way to then grab the next object after the match? So a user clicks next button, which will then load the next object?

Comment: @Xtian: Yes. If you read through the linked documentation, the iterator function we hand to `each` will receive two arguments (I didn't use them above) when called: The index of the item we're visiting, and a reference to it (e.g., `function(index, item)`). So if you find a match, then the *next* item after the match will be at `all[index+1]` (assuming the match wasn't at the very end).

Comment: this makes sense, i added a var matchNext and put this in my if statement: matchNext = match[i + 1];  but this isn't working?

Comment: @Xtian: See my comment above. You want to index into `all`, not `match`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var t={};

$.each(all, function(i, item){

  if (item['shortname']=="name") {
    t=this;
    return false;
  }

});
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah ... nevermind... if it was an html dom so i regullary make it jquery objkect....

Comment: And why use `item` in one place, but `this` in another?

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) solution:

```
var showThis = _.find( all, function ( elem ) {
    return elem.shortname === name;
});
```

Plain JavaScript solution:

```
var showThis = all.filter( function ( elem ) {
  return elem.shortname === name;
})[ 0 ];
```

*Btw, `.filter()` is an ES5 array iteration method. The ES5 array iteration methods are not implemented in IE8 and older versions. (You can easily polyfill them though.)*

Comment: @Xtian: Note that Šime's used a feature of JavaScript taht won't exist on about half of the browsers people use in the wild; you'll have to shim it if you use it. Šime: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118021/javascript-answers-using-es5-features-warn-or-not

Comment: @T.J.Crowder "Half of the browsers" is a bit misleading. Only IE8 and IE7 are affected. Those two browsers comprise about 20-30% of page-views (depending on location).

Comment: `@Šime`: No, half is about right, and much closer than 20-30%. I did the math in [my answer to the linked question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118023/134069). (Also, IE6 is affected; remember that *more than a quarter* of Chinese web surfers use IE6; a number which is thankfully *finally* coming down.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Oh yes, we mustn't forget about the Chinese IE6 surfers `:P` Seriously, I don't think they matter.

Comment: `@Šime`: Wow. Okay, maybe you don't think they matter, but remember that people developing applications for the Chinese market use this site too. And even disregarding China, it's at least 30% of the rest of the users in the world (not just IE8 and earlier, but the 3.5% using Firefox 3.6, etc., etc.). That's non-trivial. Hence my position, and that of the majority of people, that if you use ES5 features when answering a question, taking two seconds to mention they may need to shim is a quick, simple, useful thing to do. It's like Google's "don't be evil": Don't lay traps for people.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My comment was specifically about IE6. I think that web-sites don't have to support that browser anymore. If IE6 support is still required, it has to be explicitly mentioned in the question.

Comment: `@Šime`: It's not just IE6. It's IE6, IE7, IE8, Firefox 3.x, and a bunch of others. You're casually ignoring **no fewer than** 30% of all web surfers even disregarding the Chinese market, and (all due respect) for no good reason. One sentence on an answer is what it takes to avoid setting a trap for someone to fall into. Why wouldn't you do that? Isn't the whole point of answering questions here *to be helpful*? Last word can be yours, I think we've beat this to death.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, alright then. I'm going to include that note in my future answers.